# ImportError: No module named rospkg

Tags: ros, rospkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to execute an scrip for hw_interface, but in the roslaunch execution the following error emerges:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/kate_global/script/hwinterface_script_kate.py", line 11, in <module>
        import rospy
      File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
      File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 52, in <module>
        import roslib
      File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
        from roslib.launcher import load_manifest  # noqa: F401
      File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
        import rospkg
    ImportError: No module named rospkg
    qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
    [KATE_interface-4] process has died [pid 17094, exit code 1, cmd /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/kate_global/script/hwinterface_script_kate.py __name:=KATE_interface __log:=/home/pi/.ros/log/99d73b08-bb8f-11ea-9c44-dca6326fbe0e/KATE_interface-4.log].
```

If I try to install rospkg with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-rospkg
```

It sais that is alredy installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-rospkg is already the newest version (1.2.8-100).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I don't know why is this happening. Any idea?

I am working on Debian 10 (64 bits) and ROS version Noetic.

Best regards.
Alessandro

EDIT:

The output of `echo $PYTHONPATH` is:

```
/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib
```

The first line of hwinterface_script_kate.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356188/importerror:-no-module-named-rospkg/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2020-07-01**:
whats the output of:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

and how did you try to execute your script?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-07-02**:
I would guess that the script you invoke `hwinterface_script_kate.py` contains a shebang line referencing `python` or `python2`. Can you please update the question with the first line of that script.

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-07-08**:
I have alredy edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this case, you should change the first line of your code with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` like @Dirk Thomas said.

---

Originally posted by [mebasoglu](https://answers.ros.org/users/51148/mebasoglu/) with karma: 38 on 2020-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr Moose](https://answers.ros.org/users/68073/mr-moose/) on 2021-01-16**:
Doesn't work. The problem appears to be how ROS changes the Python environment relative to where it copies and runs python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

None of the above solutions worked for me. I changed several times the python version and nothing. The only thing that worked for me was

```
 sudo pip install --target=/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages rospkg
```

---

Originally posted by [Bernat Gaston](https://answers.ros.org/users/44457/bernat-gaston/) with karma: 119 on 2022-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ArmanAsq](https://answers.ros.org/users/110864/armanasq/) on 2022-07-28**:
It worked for me.
Thanks a lot.